# Custom Object Download Manager

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, completionhandler

I am stuck here. I have a custom class that I create to download images. What I want to do is make a completion block for one of the method.

For eg:

```
CustomObj *obj = [[CustomObj alloc] init];
[obj downloadImage:url withCompletion:(BOOL *finished) {

 //do stuff
}];
```

Problem is in CustomObj, I use 2 NSURLSessions to download image and each of these are blocks. Basically first session start first, then completion of first session, will run 2nd session, and at the completion of 2nd session, I want to fire my custom completion. No idea how to do this. Pls help thanks.

Comment: so whats the issue with this?

Comment: how to make completion for custom class, which is fired after another completion is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this

In `Customobj.h`

```
+(void)downloadImage:(NSString *) url
                 success:(void(^)(BOOL finished))success
                 failure:(void(^)(NSString *errorMessage))failure;
```

In `Customobj.m`

```
+(void)downloadImage:(NSString *) url
             success:(void(^)(BOOL finished))success
             failure:(void(^)(NSString *errorMessage))failure

{
    if(success)
  {
    success(success);
  }
  else{
    failure(errorMessage);
  }
}
```

Then you can use it like :

```
 [Customobj downloadImage:url success:^(BOOL finished) {

    } failure:^(NSString *errorMessage) {

    }];
```

Comment: I get error at success(YES); Implicit declaration of "success" is invalid in C99

Comment: Ok, this seems to work. The error was my bad. I'll accept this answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely nest blocks within the others.

Here is a small example just to show how it works. Obviously the methods here are pretty blank but it is just so you have an idea :

```
- (void) networkCallWithCompletionBlock:(void (^)(NSString *response))completed {
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        completed(@"My amazing response");
    });
}

- (void) methodWithCompletionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL success))completed {
    [self networkCallWithCompletionBlock:^(NSString *response) {
        completed([response isEqualToString:@"My amazing response"]);
    }];
}

- (void) buttonPress() {
    [self methodWithCompletionBlock:^(BOOL success) {
        NSLog(@"%@", @(success));
    }];
}
```

Whenever you call the method `buttonPress`, it will trigger the chain of two asynchronous method, and the message will be printed 0.5 seconds after.

Comment: Seems legit. I'll give this a try.